# PHP Header Redirect on Form Submission Not Working

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to let the script do a redirection on click of the submit button by using the PHP header function. However, it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how i could get it to work with PHP header function?

Here's part of the function that i thought is relevant:-

```
switch ( $service ) {
    case 'mailchimp' :
        $lastname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['et_lastname'] );
        $email = array( 'email' => $email );

        if ( ! class_exists( 'MailChimp' ) )
            require_once( get_template_directory() . '/includes/subscription/mailchimp/mailchimp.php' );

        $mailchimp_api_key = et_get_option( 'divi_mailchimp_api_key' );

        if ( '' === $mailchimp_api_key ) die( json_encode( array( 'error' => __( 'Configuration error: api key is not defined', 'Divi' ) ) ) );


            $mailchimp = new MailChimp( $mailchimp_api_key );

            $merge_vars = array(
                'FNAME' => $firstname,
                'LNAME' => $lastname,
            );

            $retval =  $mailchimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'         => $list_id,
                'email'      => $email,
                'merge_vars' => $merge_vars,
            ));

            if ( isset($retval['error']) ) {
                if ( '214' == $retval['code'] ){
                    $error_message = str_replace( 'Click here to update your profile.', '', $retval['error'] );
                    $result = json_encode( array( 'success' => $error_message ) );
                } else {
                    $result = json_encode( array( 'success' => $retval['error'] ) );
                }
            } else {
                $result = json_encode( array( 'success' => $success_message ) );
            }

        die( $result );
        break;
```

I tried to replace the `$result` with `header("Location: http://www.example.com/");` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you calling this PHP script via AJAX? If so, you should return something like `array('success' => true, 'location' => 'http://...')` and do the redirect in your ajax callback.

Comment: @Bjorn, does it mean i should replace $result = json_encode( array( 'success' => $success_message) ); with $result = json_encode( array('success' => true, 'location' => 'http://www.example.com') ); ?

Comment: @Bjorn it returns true, but no redirection was carried out. via AJAX.

Comment: It will not redirect unless you update your javascript as well. Can you include the relevant js-code (where you set up/handle the ajax call)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't just change the code to  `$result = header('Location: ...')` is actually quite simple. With this javascript call as an example:

```
$.post('/myscript.php', { et_lastname: 'Doe', email: 'j.doe@example.com' }, function(data) {
    // do something
});
```

What happens:

1. An HTTP-POST call is made via AJAX to `/myscript.php`
2. Your code is executed, subscribing the given email address.
3. The PHP code returns a 301
4. The AJAX call will follow the redirect, but your browser will stay on the same page.

What you actually want is that when the AJAX call was successful, the browser redirects to another page. To achieve that, you'll need to update both your PHP and Javascript.

In your PHP, you'll have to return the location you want the browser to redirect to, for example:

```
<?php
    $result = json_encode(array('location' => 'https://example.com/path/to/page'));
```

Right now, the PHP script just returns an json-response with a location key. The browser, nor the javascript doesn't do anything with that information unless we tell it to do so:

```
$.post('/myscript.php', { et_lastname: 'Doe', email: 'j.doe@example.com' }, null, 'json').done(function(data) {
    // do something ...
    // redirect browser to page we provided in the ajax response
    window.location = data.location;
}).fail(function(data) {
    // handle the error
});
```